# Rails JSON to editable UI in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a json object in my DB which I want to break out to radio buttons on a view, and then store back as a JSON object in the DB.

on the model i added serialize as json

```
  serialize :lbrTableJson, JSON
```

in the DB I store the below seed:

```
lbrTableJson: {
        "Catagory 1": [
            {
                name: "A",
                Level: "1"
            },
            {
                name: "B",
                Level: "2"
            }
        ],
        "Catagory 2": [
            {
                name: "A",
                Level: "2"
            },
            {
                name: "B",
                Level: "3"
            }
        ]
    },
```

then on the view I have

```
    <% @report.lbrTableJson.each do |key, value| %>
    <% value.each do |aFactor| %>
    <%= aFactor["name"]  %> 
    <%= f.select aFactor["Level"], options_for_select([1,2,3]) %>
    <% end %>
```

which shows correctly on the view as a dropdown of 1,2,3 but doesn't set them to existing value in the JSON object.

How can I programatically break this JSON out into selections then save it back in? Do I need to use JS or is there a nice rails way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The Rails way would be be [not use a JSON column](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/) and instead setup a table, model, assocation and to use fields_for together with accepts_nested_attributes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: Thank you but this field will contain a large number of records which ar not repeated. I think our prefer to avoid having hundreds of empty columns and a complex query structure. Maybe this task is not rails strong point. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Just need to read the parameters back into the json on update.  If you follow a naming convention and build a little scaffolding you can build the form automatically from the json and read it back in automatically.  It's not trivial, but it's not hard -- just have to invest a bit in the scaffolding.